# How can I get a list of pull requests for all repos through the GitHub API?

Tags: api, github-api, pull-request

I want to obtain the list of pull requests for all repos of a specific reviewer or author through the GitHub API.

I've followed the instructions at http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/ but when I query /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls, I've to specify the particular repository but I want to list all the repositories.

Does anyone know how to get a complete list of pull requests for all repos of a specific reviewer through the API.